# Is it possible passing html elements attributes with a PHP form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I would like to know if I can send html elements attributes (like `id`, `class` or `title`) with a classic `post form` and save them in a db.

I know this is possible with `AJAX`, saving the values in variables with javascript and then sending them to a PHP file with `$.post` or `$.ajax`

But is it possible with a normal post submit form?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Only the value- and the name-attribute are sent to the server when you use a classic submit. There is no way to get more attributes then these two.
So, you are forced to use javascript.

The following might be an alternative to your proposed $.post-function: you can adjust a form and then submit it using javascript. So, apart from the two JQuery-functions you mention, there is also a form.submit() method. You will have to manipulate the value- and name-attribute of the form-elements and then use .submit() to send those to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i see its not possible but you have opened my eyes giving me an idea with the name attribute. I could manipulate it with javascript with the value i want, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, only names and values are posted.

Comment: Thanks, yes i see its not possible